# Windows 8 App / Loading screen

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1

Every application in Windows 8 starts from this kind of view
(below is camera application) :

[image]

My question is :

Is this possible to change programmatically this view for 
progress bar (C# or XAML) or any other animation ?
Or is this view related with time computer need to start application so
we can not use resource of our app yet ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change how the launch screen is displayed. You can only change the picture and color.

However, the way to extend the launch screen is to make sure your app's first action is to display another launch screen (typically identical to the first with an added progress bar) while the rest of the app is getting ready. This approach is described in [this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868191.aspx).

Please keep in mind that an extended load screen might not be the best user experience. After all the user is still waiting for the app to launch. I recommend that you optimize launch time to avoid using the extended launch screen if you can. I cover this in more detail in [my book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735682631) (sorry for the shameless plug).

Comment: Nice find on the guide! I knew the approach but didn't know Microsoft published a tutorial :) +1

Comment: Yeah . I have found explanation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868191.aspx

Answer (score 1):

That screen is displayed while the runtime is starting your application. Its an image as defined by your application, so to my knowledge, there is no way to inject logic.

However, you *can* make your app "start" fast (so that the runtime removes the "loading" image), then put up a splash screen while the rest of your content loads. The NFL for Windows 8 app does a good job of this, as do several other apps.

Comment: What you mean by "make youre app start fast"?

Comment: @Radek Basically don't do any long operations in constructors/loading functions. Then your app will be "ready" faster so you can put up a splash screen while these long running ops finish. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh849088.aspx for some tips on how to do this in Javascript